# gdb 7.12.1-48.el7 requests "debuginfo-install" but these packages are already installed?

Tags: gdb, redhat

I start a binary under a debugger, let it run for a bit, then ctrl-c.  The gdb tells me:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 libattr-2.4.46-12.el7.x86_64 libcap-2.22-9.el7.x86_64
libcom_err-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64 libselinux-2.5-11.el7.x86_64
libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64 libuuid-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64 libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64
ncurses-libs-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.x86_64 openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 pcre-8.32-17.el7.x86_64 
xerces-c-3.1.1-8.el7_4.1.x86_64 xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64
```

However I consult with my sysadm and he says these packages are already installed!

I pick `libuuid` at random to drill down on.  I find the package and from that the file contents:

```
[~]# rpm -qa | grep libuuid
libuuid-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64

[~]# rpm -ql libuuid-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1                 <----- just a symbolic link
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0             <----- WE'LL SEE THIS IN LINE 3 OF STRACE GREP, BELOW
/usr/share/doc/libuuid-2.23.2           <---- just a dir
/usr/share/doc/libuuid-2.23.2/COPYING   <---- just a doc
```

I then use `strace -o gdb.trace gdb MyBinary` to capture all system calls made by the debugger to see what files it's reading:

```
> grep /usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1 gdb.trace
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=16, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", "libuuid.so.1.3.0", 4095) = 16
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20040, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0.debug", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0.debug", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=16, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", "libuuid.so.1.3.0", 4095) = 16
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20040, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=16, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", "libuuid.so.1.3.0", 4095) = 16
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20040, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=16, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", "libuuid.so.1.3.0", 4095) = 16
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20040, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.gdb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=16, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1", "libuuid.so.1.3.0", 4095) = 16
lstat("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20040, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0-gdb.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Soooooo... why is GDB asking that a package be installed that contains, basically, only files it's already reading??!!

---

OS is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

We have a gcc 4.8.5 as the default install, but have gcc 6 and 7 installed to be activated with commands `scl enable devtoolset-6 tcsh` and `scl enable devtoolset-7 tcsh`.  I'm using 6 for this project.  Before I drilled down I was confident that it would turn out that the library was only being searched for under `/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/` but strace proves otherwise!

g++ version is: `g++ (GCC) 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)`
gdb version is: `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.12.1-48.el7`

Comment: Your system administrator needs to install the debuginfo packages corresponding to all those packages that gdb complained about. The packages are named `libuuid-debuginfo` and similar. There may be some other dependencies that need to be installed, too; sometimes the debuginfo package includes source code, sometimes source code is in another package. The `debuginfo-install` command will take care of finding those dependencies. If doing that fixes things (or not), let us know.

Comment: Mark, 1) I consulted with my sysadm and he says these packages are already installed.  And the strace output above shows that the debugger is actually finding the installed files, such as /usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0.

Comment: Your `rpm -qa | grep libuuid` output shows that `libuuid-debuginfo` isn't installed. The debuginfo for libuuid is not in `/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0`, it's in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0.debug`, which your strace output shows does not exist (ENOENT). It should be a ~ 90KB file.

Comment: Oh, OK, Mark, thanks for sticking with me.  I wasn't reading quite carefully enough.  I need packages with files with the same name as the library but with .debug appended.  I'm following up with my sysadm to see whether debuginfo-install failed to install them, or whether the sysadm didn't run the debuginfo-install I requested because he thought it would only try to install libraries we already had.